# Django - outer join 2 querysets into 1 queryset without raw sql

Tags: django, outer-join, django-queryset

Is there an option to create a queryset that outer joins 2 querysets without raw sql?

I have one queryset that hits 1 table -

`queryset1 = Model1.objects.all()`

I have another queryset that hits the **same** table and does some aggregation -

```
queryset2 = Model1.objects.filter(relatedField__days__range=(2013-05-11, 2013-05-13)).annotate(s1=Sum(relatedField__field1), s2=Sum(relatedField__field2))
```

I want to left outer join the first queryset with the second without raw sql.
As you can see, the second queryset is a subset of the first.
The problem is, that I want to return all the objects in the table.
If an object didn't pass the filter I want to present 0 in the sum fields.
That's the reason I want outer join.

Was that clear enough?

Comment: Give an actual use case. The example you gave might responded to in many ways. Be as specific as you can to get quick and accurate answer.

Comment: This seems redundant? Without knowing more i'd say that you could skip doing the first queryset all together.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know off the top of my head but you could probably build an empty model that is a proxy of the original and use that.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models